# Phonegap with iphone

Tags: iphone, cordova

I want to know about how to phonegap communicate with server in iphone...
and how to implement phonegap o  iphone..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PhoneGap basically wraps a web app and packages it for distribution as an app.

As it is basically a web app you communicate with a server the same way you would in a web app, ie. Ajax.

Comment: Let me add a clarification for future readers. PhoneGap --at least on iOS-- accesses files on your iPhone using file:// URLs. It will talk to your backend server over AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to create a "Hello World" app for iOS using PhoneGap - http://www.phonegap.com/start#ios-x4.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing a primer using phonegap. The JS framework i'm using is Sencha Touch and it goes great with PhoneGap. Go through the following tutorial/example:

http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap/